# Disadvantages of PDO (PHP Data objects)

Tags: php, pdo

Everything I've read so far about PDO (PHP Data Objects) is almost too good to be true.

I mean:

- Its faster then mysql or mysqli.
- It has the same syntax for multiple database drivers.
- with prepared statements it is secure for SQL injection.
- you can fetch data directly into a object.

But what are the disadvantages of PDO?

Comment: Same thing as always with PHP: type unsafe means an unsolvable mess if the developer isn't disciplined.  Bug hunting hell.  The usual.

Comment: @bdares It's actually pretty type safe, and your argument is against PHP and its very nature, not against PDO.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the same syntax for all database. If you mean sql, you are wrong. Pdo is a data-access abstraction layer and not a database abstraction, sql remains different. If you mean in making queries, then you might be right, but writing a simple wrapper provides you the same thing if you want to change the database type.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Everything I've read so far about PDO (PHP Data Objects) is almost too good to be true.

I use PDO every day, and that's for a reason. I did write a wrapper over it though, because the default PDO instance does things I don't like (e.g. fail silently), and the API could've been a whole lot better. Configuration with constants is just not my default approach. Also, I've created some convenience methods.

> Its faster then mysql or mysqli.

Is it? I don't know where you picked this up, and it might well be true, but I haven't heard of PDO being faster than the native MySQL libraries.

> It has the same syntax for multiple database drivers.

Sort of. I use PostgreSQL a lot, and the code is different from when you're working with MySQL. This makes sense though, as PostgreSQL works with named sequences, while MySQL works with "auto increment", which is a sequence per table. There are differences between databases that PDO can not abstract, even if it's just for database *access*.

> with prepared statements it is secure for sql injection.

You can [prepare statements with mysqli](http://nl.php.net/mysqli_prepare) too, so I don't see this as a definitive upside. I do generally use prepared statements though, and I like the :field syntax PDO provides.

> But where are the disadvantages of PDO, something that has so many pros must also have a contra.

The API is less than intuitive for me, I think the API of mysqli makes more sense. Nevertheless, if you write a wrapper for it yourself, it's a very decent library. Here's [the wrapper I wrote](http://code.google.com/p/sphoof/source/browse/lib/database.php) to make using PDO a little bit more sane, there are many more examples drifting on the internet though.

**EDIT**: Oh, and James Anderson is right; it has poor Oracle support. I don't use Oracle, so I don't see that as a huge downside though.

Comment: PDO may be faster than mysql_* when using a prepared statement many times since less data needs to be sent to the mysql server for a prepared statement, however it is not faster when doing many prepared statements and executing them few times and it's definitely not faster than mysqli.

Comment: In my vision PDO may be *faster than mysql* in **not permitting/making harder for lame programmers with no decent db background, but a solid OO one**, to query the db 26 times with bad queries instead of just one with the *right* query.

Comment: ^ This times a million.

Answer (score 5):

**Bind mechanism doesn't work with column or table names.**

Simple examples:

```
CREATE TABLE :bar (rowId int)

SELECT :foo FROM :bar
```

On the bright side, this is not something you often need or want to do.

But when you do... PDO leaves you hanging.  The solution is manually concating together your query strings while doing by-hand escaping:

```
$foo = some_escape_logic( $dirtyFoo );
$bar = some_escape_logic( $dirtyBar );

$db->query( "SELECT {$foo} FROM {$bar}" );
```

**SQL results always returned as strings**

fetch() returns an array of string values, even if the SQL table types are numeric.  For example, a table with bigint/string/bigint columns returns:

```
array( 'rowId' => '1', 'name' => 'Fred', 'age' => '12' );
```

instead of:

```
array( 'rowId' => 1, 'name' => 'Fred', 'age' => 12 );
```

As a positive, you'll never lose precision from a mismatch between PHP and SQL types.  The type juggling in PHP also ensures that you'll seldom even notice that the data was originally encoded as strings.

As a negative, this can be a pain when passing DB results to something like json_encode(), since you'll end up with the numeric values quoted:

```
{ "rowId": "1", "name": "Fred", "age": "12" }
```

instead of

```
{ "rowId": 1, "name": "Fred", "age": 12 }
```

In an ideal world, auto-casting output types from fetch() would be controllable via an optional argument.

Comment: I found the first problem quoted here some time ago. Turned out when I learned enough that I was doing the database relationship scheme wrong. I fixed it and never found this problem again. Anyway +1

Comment: SQL results always returned as strings -- Seems to be the case with the mysql driver, but not the postgres driver.  If you're using postgres with PDO it will try to map values to the closest equivalent PHP type

Answer (score 5):

> Its faster then mysql or mysqli.

wrong. in the real life it's slower in general.

> It has the same syntax for multiple database drivers.

for the API functions - yes, of course. but it wont help you with different SQL dialects.

> with prepared statements it is secure for sql injection.

to be secured against sql injections, **four** matters needs to be properly escaped:

- strings
- numbers
- identifiers
- operators

while PDO covers only first two.

Answer (score 3):

Two downsides that I know of:

No or poor Oracle support!

Some performance hits on large result sets.

As far as I am concerned the first "downside" is yet another reason to avoid Oracle. The second seldom matters.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading somewhere that one of the disadvantage of PDO is that it takes a bit more querying time. (Sorry i dont have reference to that article), hopefully some experts can tell about it.